# How to Handle Button Click Events in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need to have a button and handle its event in jQuery. And I am writing this code but it'snot working. Did I miss something?

```
<!-- Begin Button -->  
<div class="demo">
<br> <br> <br>   
<input id = "btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Release"/>
<br> <br> <br>  
</div>
<!-- End Button -->
```

And in the javascript file

```
function btnClick()
{
    //    button click
    $("#btnSubmit").button().click(function(){
        alert("button");
    });    
}
```

Comment: Why not just take it out of the enclosing `btnClick` function? I don't see what that adds

Answer (score 307, accepted):

You have to put the event handler in the $(document).ready() event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        alert("button");
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 34):

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
    alert("button");
});
```

or

```
//Use this code if button is appended in the DOM
$(document).on('click','#btnSubmit',function(){
    alert("button");
});
```

See documentation for more information:
https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Button appended in the dom thing is always an issue if using notification like sweetalert. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Emphasis on if element is appended. So useful. Thank you

Comment: Appended to DOM +1!

Answer (score 28):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $('your selector').bind("click",function(){
            // your statements;
     });

     // you can use the above or the one shown below

     $('your selector').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         // your statements;
     });


});
```

Comment: Good because is the onlyone who insert the preventDefault()

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.  Therefore this would be better: `$('your selector').on("click", ...);`

Answer (score 14):

Try This:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btnClick', function(){ 
    alert("button is clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <button id="btnClick">Click me</button>
```

Comment: This version has the benefit of still working if #btnClick is created after this script runs.

Answer (score 9):

```
 $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        alert("button");
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
    alert("Hello");
  });
});
</script>

<input type="button" id="button" value="Click me">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#Button1").click(function() {

        alert("hello");

    });

    }
    );

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function(event){
    alert("Button Clicked");
});
```

or as you are using submit button so you can write your code in form's validate event like

```
$('#myForm').validate(function(){
    alert("Hello World!!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#btn").click(function() {
    alert("email")
});

</script>
```