# PHP javascript problems

Tags: javascript, php

I am totally new in php, so my opology if this question seems weird to you.

I have one php file (index.php) something like,

```
echo "
    <div>  
        <FORM name='myform' id='myform' method='post' action=''>

        // I fetch data from mysql and populate dropdown list. Tha't work fine.
        // Then I have one submit button when I click on that

        echo "<button id='showButton' type='submit'> Show </button>"; 

        </FORM>
";
```

Then I have one process.js file something like,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#showButton').click(function () {

        // Here I make one AJAX call to php file (fetch_more_data.php), which fetch more data from database
        // This also works fine

    });

});
```

In fetch_more_data.php I fetch more data and display in table using

```
echo "
    <script type = 'text/javascript' src = 'edit.js'></script>

    <table ...>

    <td>
        <button id="myButton"></button>
    </td>

    </table>

";
```

This is also work fine. but I want to edit one table cell and for that I need to write some java script code. I want to write on click function for myButton in Javascripr, for that I have written on edit.js file,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myButton').click(function () {

        alert('Hello');

    });

});
```

The problem is `$('#myButton').click(function ()` never called. I have spent long time but being a beginner my search options are limited. 
I would appriciate if someone solve this problem.

Regards,

Comment: please wrap your code up propperly before i think of an answer

Comment: you cannot use `echo` within the contents of another `echo`

Comment: You're using jquery.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508319/jquery-input-button-click-event-listener here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/WTzKR/

Comment: make sure your edit.js is being read by your fetch_more_data.php file

Comment: ID's are unique so you may have some conflict there, add it as a class i.e. class="editButton" then call it like $('.editButton').click(function () //rest of your code

Comment: Is the issue because form is submitted instead function execution?

Comment: Hi Thank you all of you for comments. @Jarek, how to get know that my  fetch_more_data.php file is connected/linked to edit.js? I have added something like echo "<script type = 'text/javascript' src = 'edit.js'></script>"; but It seems both files are not linked together.

Comment: try using firebug and double check if both jquery and your edit.js get included in the rendered html page

Comment: Yes, I can see both JQuery and edit.js are included.

Comment: Can I see if myButton Click function is being called or not in firebug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try calling it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '#myButton', function(){
    alert('hi');
  });
});
```

hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
$('#myButton').live('click',function () {

alert('Hello');

});

});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. Can I see if myButton callback function is called in firebug or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(document).on("click", "#myButton", function () {

alert('Hello');

 });
});
```

Since the html is being added to the DOM dynamically, you need to handle it using [**Event Delegation**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in jQuery

Comment: Thanks for comments, it seems I have no connect between fetch_more_data.php and edit.js. Ihave already inclduing echo "<script type = 'text/javascript' src = 'edit.js'></script>"; in fetch_more_data.php but no effect

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are not loading the jQuery

Download the jquery on the same folder where is your php file and add this line in your code

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```