# Why does the javascript/flask client/server setup returns None on the python side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I would like to setup a simple way of having javascript in a client web page to communicate with a python server. The final goal is to create a simple web-browser based game for 2-4 players which access some page, and where they can do something (and see some graphics generated by `three.js`). Therefore, I would like to have the client in javascript, and the backend in python (because python is great).

My previous questions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45276485/how-to-fix-sending-data-via-javascript-ajax-jquery-to-python-server) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45265760/javascript-python-client-webserver-example-not-working). Now I tried yet another example following [this description](https://www.google.fr/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=complete%20javascript%20python%20communication%20example&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=P8F1WZi9CZPFaNi0vYgP) but again it didn't work.

Here is the full code, `index.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // setup some JSON to use
    var cars = [
      { "make":"Porsche", "model":"911S" },
      { "make":"Mercedes-Benz", "model":"220SE" },
      { "make":"Jaguar","model": "Mark VII" }
    ];

    window.onload = function() {
      // setup the button click
      document.getElementById("theButton").onclick = function() {
        doWork();
      };
    };

    function doWork() {
      // ajax the JSON to the server
      $.post("receiver", cars, function(){

      });
      // stop link reloading the page
     event.preventDefault();
    }
    </script>
    This will send data using AJAX to Python:<br /><br />
    <a href="" id="theButton">Click Me</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is the python code:

```
import sys

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, Response
import random, json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def output():
    # serve index template
    return render_template('index.html', name='Joe')

@app.route('/receiver', methods = ['POST'])
def worker():
    # read json + reply
    data = request.get_json() # HERE
    print(data)
    result = ''

    for item in data:
        # loop over every row
        result += str(item['make']) + '\n'

    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run!
    app.run()
```

The problem is that the data received in the python code (HERE) the data is `None`.

I would appreciate ideas on how this can be fixed.

Comment: See this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001229/how-to-get-posted-json-in-flask You must set the mimetype of your request to 'application/json' for request.get_json() to work.

Comment: The solution suggests to use the method `request.get_json()` which I am using already. Otherwise, please provide the exact code snippet on how to fix my code.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer:
[How to get POSTed json in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001229/how-to-get-posted-json-in-flask)

The problem comes from your jQuery post request: the default mimetype is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" when using $.post, try using [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) with contentType "application/json", otherwise Flask will be unable to know that the data you send is JSON, and will return None when you call get_json()

Another idea is to use [data](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.data) instead of get_json(), then parse the result:

```
data = request.data
dataDict = json.loads(data)
```

Comment: Maybe it works,  but nothing is printed out. When I redirect the printout to `sys.stderr` I get the error: `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes`