# Button doesn't work in php with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, web

my button doesn't work when I click on it nothing happens.
This is my HTML for it:

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" action="senden.php" method="get">
        <ul><div>
                <li>
            <button id="testbutton" name="testbutton" value="abgesendet2" type="button">test</button>

            <p> Felder mit einem Stern müssen ausgefüllt werden! </p>
        </ul>

    </form>
```

and this is my jQuery for it (the button is in a form):

```
<script> 
        jQuery('document').ready(function(){

            $("#myform").on('click', '#testbutton', function(){
                alert("test");
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Where is your `<form id="myform"  ..>` ? Please click the `<>` and add the rest of the relevant HTML.

Comment: please add your full HTML so that we can help\

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4323877/6140684)

Comment: Use  `$("#testbutton").on('click', function(){`

Comment: @Rishi doesnt make a difference really

Comment: Your code works. Which error are you getting? Are you including jquery?

Comment: @GiacomoPittalis I dont get any error and yes Im including jquery

Comment: It is very odd, are you using firebug console to check errors?

Comment: Btw, I added a jsfiddle in my answer below, do it works?

Comment: Open your browser's console and check for error messages.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to make a small change. Attach the click directly to the target button and it will work.

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
    $("#testbutton").on('click', function(){
        alert("test");
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="testbutton" name="testbutton" value="abgesendet2" type="button">test</button>
```

Comment: how do I attach it directly to the button?

Comment: This line in my code form above does just that. Target directly the testbutton:
`$("#testbutton").on('click',function(){ `

Comment: ok, then you need to check if you get any errors in the console, in Chrome - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/ You should be able to see if, by any chance the jQuery library is missing.

Comment: This is no different than what the OP is doing, so why make the change?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems working correctly, are you sure you were including jquery?
Here is what I tested:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script> 
    jQuery('document').ready(function(){

        $("#myform").on('click', '#testbutton', function(){
            alert("test");
        });

    });
</script>   


<form id="myform" name="myform" action="senden.php" method="get">
<ul><div>
    <li>
        <button id="testbutton" name="testbutton" value="abgesendet2" type="button">test</button>

        <p> Felder mit einem Stern müssen ausgefüllt werden! </p>
    </ul>

</form>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/benxo945/) too. Do it works?

Comment: So it must work in your environment! Are you working locally? How are you including jquery?

Comment: Really? Not even a "Thank you"?