# Category system for carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using [lightGallery](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery) with [cycle2 plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) and I have categories for my image and when I clicked any categories my images must change with clicked category how can I do that ? any example ?

my `a[data-id]` is category images parents and my `li#id` category names

I want to share with you my structure, here you are please:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mySlideShow').cycle({
    pauseOnHover: true,
    pager: "#single-pager",
    log:false,
    pagerTemplate: "<img src='{{src}}' width=48 height=48>",
    slides: ">a"
  });

  $(".mySlideShow").lightGallery({
    exThumbImage: "data-exthumbimage",
    download: false,
    thumbnail: true,
    loadYoutubeThumbnail: true,
    youtubeThumbSize: 'default',
    loadVimeoThumbnail: true,
    vimeoThumbSize: 'thumbnail_medium',

  });
})
```

```css
.single-gallery {
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
}

.mySlideShow {
  height: 494px;
  background: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#single-pager img {
  width: 49.3px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 2px;
}

.gallery-categories {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20000;
  left: 0;
  top: 10%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery-categories li {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lightgallery/latest/css/lightgallery.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="single-gallery" id="single-gallery">
  <div class="single-gallery-carousel">
    <div class="slideshow-area">

      <div class="mySlideShow">
        <a data-src="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/11.jpg" data-exthumbimage="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/11.jpg" data-id="naturel">
          <img data-poster="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/11.jpg" src="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/11.jpg">
        </a>
        <a class="video" href="https://vimeo.com/1084537" data-src="img/assets/otel-detay-slide-1.jpg" data-exthumbimage="img/assets/otel-detay-slide-1.jpg" data-id="naturel">
          <img src="img/assets/otel-detay-slide-1.jpg" />
        </a>
        <a data-src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/h494/2017-03/otel_aurum-didyma-spa-beach-resort_sReNOBXcinbZI7lNGf3x.jpg" data-exthumbimage="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/h494/2017-03/otel_aurum-didyma-spa-beach-resort_sReNOBXcinbZI7lNGf3x.jpg"
          data-id="naturel">
          <img data-poster="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/h494/2017-03/otel_aurum-didyma-spa-beach-resort_sReNOBXcinbZI7lNGf3x.jpg" src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/h494/2017-03/otel_aurum-didyma-spa-beach-resort_sReNOBXcinbZI7lNGf3x.jpg">
        </a>
        <a data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/tulips-lightbox.jpg" data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/tulips-lightbox.jpg" data-id="animals">
          <img class="lazy" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/tulips-lightbox.jpg" src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/tulips-lightbox.jpg">
        </a>
          <img class="lazy" src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/golden-wheat-field-lightbox.jpg" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/golden-wheat-field-lightbox.jpg">
        </a>
        <a data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg" data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg"
          data-id="sports">
          <img class="lazy" src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg">
        </a>
        <a data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg" data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg"
          data-id="sports">
          <img class="lazy" src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg">
        </a>
        <a data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg" data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg" data-id="animals">
          <img class="lazy" src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg">
        </a>
        <a data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/daffodil-flowers-lightbox.jpg" data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/daffodil-flowers-lightbox.jpg"
          data-id="sports">
          <img class="lazy" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/daffodil-flowers-lightbox.jpg" src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/daffodil-flowers-lightbox.jpg">
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- cycle slideshow-->
    </div>
    <div id="single-pager" class="center external"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-categories">
    <h1>Select a Categories</h1>
    <ul>
      <li id="sports">Sports</li>
      <li id="animals">Animals</li>
      <li id="naturel">Naturel</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/2.1.6/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.3.9/js/lightgallery.min.js"></script>
```

[and if you want to see on codepen please click here](https://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/GWBpbe)

Comment: You want images which `data-id` attribute match the clicked `li`'s `id` attribute to change? Based on your question you could also want to change the images category.

Comment: yes exactly I want to this

Comment: I mean all my image has `data-id` and my li has `id` and if data-id match width id than show the match id or images (sorry about my english)

Comment: I edited your question to make it more clear. What you want is to [handle an event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323848/how-to-handle-button-click-events-in-jquery), [select images based on their attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2487751/4068240) and change them. As it's not clear _how_ you want to change them I can't refer to anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question it's unclear where your skill level is and either your problem is technical or conceptual. Let's try to cover both...

---

**Your category system could be realized as follows:**

First of all we have to listen to the click event and react on that.
As you are using jQuery the following will work:

```
$('.gallery-categories li').on('click', function(event) {
    var category = $(event.target).attr('id');
    console.debug(category + ' selected!');
});
```

From now on, every time a user clicks on a `li` underneath your `.gallery-selector` the event handler is invoked. Note that this function does not check whether `id` is set or not.

Now we want to select all elements matching your category:

```
// this happens in our event handler too
var $items = $('.mySlideShow a[data-id="' + category + '"]');
```

...Iterate over them and change something:

```
$items.each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

**There we are:**

```
$('.gallery-categories li').on('click', function(event) {
    var category = $(event.target).attr('id');
    var $items = $('.mySlideShow a[data-id="' + category + '"]');
    $items.each(function() {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWPxpa?editors=1111)

Comment: thanks for your help..my english is not enought to tell something..for example if I clicked naturel my naturel image will be open will thumbnail or if I clicked sports sports images will be open with thumbnails

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment

Comment: I mean this example just give a border to carousel.my question was different..I have 3 categories and when I clicked my naturel categories than I want to show naturel images or if I clicked animals than animals images must be shown

Comment: Yes you can change the bordered class to anything else, it's just an example indicating how to move on. Your question says "change", not "show". I won't write you the  whole code for this.

Comment: thanks for everything I'm new on jquery and my english is bad thank you so much