# Execute form action without redirecting to another page or reloading current page

Tags: javascript

I have the file user.php and the form inside it:

```
<form method="post" action="bubble.php" id="myForm" name="myForm">
    <input id="input" type="text">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I need to execute action bubble.php file but without redirecting to another page or reloading current page. I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can be done easily with Javascript. Please read e.g. about JQuery. The same is answered e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323848/how-to-handle-button-click-events-in-jquery