# How can I make a script to work after a click

Tags: jquery

I have the code below that gives a style to the last word inside an element with a particular class and works fine.

This class is inside a grid of articles and when I click a filter that loads (without page reload) different articles, the new articles have not that style.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.products h2.entry-title').html(function(index, curHTML) {
       var text = curHTML.split(/[\s-]/),
           newtext = '<span style="color:#fbb316;">' + text.pop() + '</span>';
       return text.join(' ').concat(' ' + newtext);
     });
    
});
```

Any help to fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: Might be better if you'd show some HTML and explain the desired outcome. You have something of an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info) here, where you're asking about your proposed solution instead of the problem. Your code looks overly complicated at first glance.

Comment: Otherwise, jQuery's click handler has been well covered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323848/how-to-handle-button-click-events-in-jquery

Comment: You change the style on document ready, so every element added after the document load will not have. the style. make a function that you call on document.ready and when the new items are loaded

Comment: You probably want to call your code after the update process is completed, though. We can't help with that without knowing more.

Answer (score 0):

This script runs once "jQuery(document).ready". This means when the document has finished loading it runs the script. The problem is later on you run a filter that loads in more elements.

Your best bet is to make this script a function:

```
$('.products h2.entry-title').html(function(index, curHTML) {
   var text = curHTML.split(/[\s-]/),
       newtext = '<span style="color:#fbb316;">' + text.pop() + '</span>';
   return text.join(' ').concat(' ' + newtext);
 });
```

Then you can call it on document ready, and call it again on success of loading in your new articles.

Although this will mean it applies a second time to the articles that were there initially (if the filter function doesn't completely remove them?). So you may have to make this function a little more clever by being able to detect which elements have already had this applied.

Comment: It is a filter like this: All, Cars, Trains, busses. So yes if you choose a category and then All, articles will be shown for the second time

Comment: In which case you will need to make sure when you run the script for a second or third time that some elements do not have it applied multiple times. Maybe through the use of a class that you could add after you have run the script and only run the script on elements without the class?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean